# assets:install creates a wrong path

Tags: directory, bundle, symfony, assets

I have a problem with the `assets:install` command in Symfony 3. As the [manual](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-smarter-assets-install-command) states,

> When executed without options, the command copies into web/ all the files found in the Resources/public/ directories of your application and bundles.

The path to my javascript file is: `src/AppBundle/Resources/public/js/script.js`

Now, when I run `php bin/console assets:install --symlink`, it puts the symlinks to `web/bundles/app/js/scripts.js`.

What I want is to make it create the symlink at `web/bundles/AppBundle/js/scripts.js`. Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

if you look inside web/bundles after running assets:install, you will see that app actually symlinks to src/AppBundle/Resources/public. so web/bundles/app/xxx should be the right convention and pointing the the right place.

web/bundles/AppBundle/xxx is the wrong convention.

Comment: Yes indeed, it does point to where I put the files originally, i.e. `src/AppBundle/Resources/public`, but I feel uncomfortable having to refer to the script as `<script type="text/javascript" src={{ asset("bundles/app/js/script.js") }}></script>`, when it originally came from a different location. What do you mean by the _right convention_, is this how `assets:install` actually works? I expect, however, I did something wrong.